# Windows 8.1 Application Store Association

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, windows-8.1

I am stuck in a strange issue. 
I reserved app names in Windows 8.1 developer portal.
In Visual Studio 2013, I created Win 8.1 store application but when I am trying to associate this application with that reserved name through store association dialog available in Visual studio 2013, Visual studio dialog is unable to find that reserved name and says that 'There is no app name to select etc...'

I have already reserved name with same Microsoft account. I am unable to find anything helpful on web.

Kindly help.